# es6 js promises: What is .catch(callback) equivalent to?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, try-catch, es6-promise

So I have this little code below

```
router.param('username', function (req, res, next, username)
{
    User.findOne({username: username}).then(function (user)
    {
        if (!user)
        {
            return res.sendStatus(404);
        }

        req.profile = user;

        return next();
    }).catch(next);
});
```

My problem is this part `.catch(next)`

What will it actually do ? Will it basically call the next() callback ? Will it pass any error into that callback i.e. next(error) ?
Or will it call it in a different way such as next(null, error) ?

I am trying to convert the above code to async/await, so will the code below do the exact same thing as the code above ?

```
router.param('username', async function (req, res, next, username)
{
    try
    {
        let user = await User.findOne({username: username});

        if (!user)
        {
            return res.sendStatus(404);
        }

        req.profile = user;

        return next();
    }
    catch(error)
    {
        next(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, your conversion is accurate. `next` will be called with the error as its only argument.

Comment: Great. Thanks for confirming that to me. You can answer the question with a reference and I would accept your answer

Comment: think of `.catch(next);` as `.catch(function(reason) { return next(reason); });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is `.catch(callback)` equivalent to?

It's equivalent to `.then(null, callback)`. Or maybe you were thinking of an [eta conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#.CE.B7-conversion), in which case it's also equivalent to `.catch(err => next(err))`.

> What will it actually do? Will it basically call the `next()` callback?

Yes, that's how callbacks work.

> Will it pass any error into that callback i.e. `next(error)`?

Yes, when the promise is rejected with that error.

> Or will it call it in a different way such as `next(null, error)`?

No, why would it?

> I am trying to convert the above code to async/await,  will my attempt do the exact same thing?

Yes, as far as `.catch` is concerned, assuming that `next` does not return anything.